# Call separate error handling module and don't continue?

Tags: vba, ms-access, reporting

I have an Access 2007 database that has a series of function calls. I'm using On Error Goto Error_Handler in all the subs and functions which calls an error handling sub which updates a table with the error info and sends an error notification email. I set this up this way so I could have only one error handling module that could be called by any sub or function.

What's happening when there's an error in one of the "non-main" subroutines or functions is that the error handling function is called (as expected and working properly) but then the code execution continues in the main procedure with whatever is after the sub that caused the error (in my case, sending a false "success" email). To be clear, ALL of my subs and functions have "On Error Goto Error_Handler" so it's not an On Error Resume Next issue.

Is there a way to have a separate error handling function called by a sub AND have the "main" procedure stop executing? (In this case, we have a form on a timer that loops through a recordset once a second and won't try to re-execute any events that have errors logged so exiting the procedure is desired to prevent false success indications.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading what you're doing correctly then it's the same trap that I fell into when I first started doing something similar. The problem is that because the error is being "handled" in the non-main routine then as far as the error handling system is concerned it's done and dusted; when the program control flow returns to the main routine then there is no longer an error condition. Let me see if I can illustrate in pseudo-code:

```
MainFunction()

   On Error Goto ErrorHandler

   Call MySubFunction

   CodeToSendSuccessEmail    

ExitPoint:
'Here we do any necessary cleanup.

Exit Function

ErrorHandler:

   Call MyErrorRoutine
   Resume ExitPoint

End Function


Function MySubFunction()

   On Error Goto ErrorHandler

   DoStuffThatCauseAnError

ExitPoint:
Exit Function

ErrorHandler:

   Call MyErrorRoutine
   Resume ExitPoint

End Function
```

---

OK, so what happens when the error occurs in MySubFunction?
It will jump to the ErrorHandler: label ***in that function***. Having done that, as far as the error handling system is concerned the error has been dealt with, so it will leave that function (in my case via the ExitPoint: label and Exit Function statement) and return to the MainFunction. When it does so there will no longer be an error in effect because it has already been handled, as a result of which the "success" e-mail will be sent.

The quickest and dirtiest way to handle situations like these is not to put any error handling in the sub-procedures at all. In that way when an error occurs it will immediately be thrown back up the call stack until it encounters an error handler which, in this case, would be in your MainFunction. When it does so it will jump straight down to the MainFunction's ErrorHandler: label.

The downside of doing it that way is that you can't then trace exactly which function the error occurred in. What I did in practice was to have my sub-routine error handlers do this:
(a) Call my tracking procedure to write the error (and the location of it) to my application's log file;
(b) Take note of the Err.Number and Err.Description in variables; then
(c) Use the values in those variables to re-raise the error after I returned to my ExitPoint: label so that it would flow back up the stack.

In that way it would ensure that I knew where the error originated from, but the main display of the error message to the user (in your case by writing to the table and sending the e-mail) would happen once, and once only; that is, by a call to my main error routine only by my top level functions.

As an aside I was quite leery about the Try/Catch syntax that is used in VB.Net and T-SQL when I first came across it but in reality it does offer a lot of advantages in error handling, including not needing to fudge around with tracing the stack when an error occurs. Not that that does you a blind bit of good working with VBA in Access; as I said it's simply an aside.